# School SSH Server PHP won't compile

Tags: php, ssh, installation, ini, server

I am trying to use php on a website that I am hosting through my University's ssh servers. However, when I visit a webpage with php, the server does not compile the code. So the page source looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My first PHP page</h1>

<?php
echo "Hello World!";
?>

</body>
</html
```

However when I access the server via ssh and enter `php -v` it returns:

```
PHP 5.4.17-pl0-gentoo (cli) (built: Jul 25 2013 22:12:37)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

Do I have to enable something in the .ini file to allow webpages to use php?

Comment: Ask the admin. This is typically configured at the webserver level.

Comment: Does it make any difference that the server is an FTP server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your webserver (Apache, Nginx or what else) need to be configured to use php. [Take a look here for example](http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my server doesn't allow dynamic content what so ever.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Neeku  No, this is the answer (server blocking PHP).